# should.have.property to verify key-value pair from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, cypress, should.js

I would like to check if key-value pair exist on a object. I use should.js with syntax: `cy.gey(selector).should('have.property', 'Compasny Feature: ', ['open space ']);` but I get this error `Error:     AssertionError: expected { Object (Company Feature: , Name: ) } to have property 'Company Feature: ' of [ 'open space ' ], but got [ 'open space ' ]` I totally have no idea which part the value does not match. or it is just a bug from should.js?

```
// debug output
{
    "Company Feature: ": [
        "open space "
    ],
    "Name: ": [
        "John, Amazon "
    ]
}
// test.ts
cy.gey(selector).should('have.property', 'Compasny Feature: ', ['open space ']);



// html
<div class="container">
    <span>
        <span class="title">Company Feature: </span>
        <span class="text">open space </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span class="title">Name: </span>
        <span class="text">John, Amazon </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is simply that you are referencing different instances of the array. You can fix this by referencing the same instance of the array like so:

```js
const testFeature = [
        "open space "
    ];
const TestData = {
    "Company Feature: ": testFeature,
    "Name: ": [
        "John, Amazon "
    ]
}
// test.ts
cy.gey(selector).should('have.property', 'Company Feature: ', testFeature);
```

Alternatively you can use `.deep` in the chain and have it check against the structure see docs: https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_property

```js
// test.ts
cy.gey(selector).should('have.deep.property', 'Company Feature: ', testFeature);
```

Comment: Hm...not quit sure what it means but obviously your solution works

Comment: What part of it are you confused about?

Comment: i am not quite sure why it is "referencing different instances of the array" i though I just simply compare a with b but i guess I see it now, it is just [1234] !== [1234]